# XML DOM button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Im having a problem with my XML DOM, where im using button onclick to for loop the tag name that I am targeting but the button won't work. Can you please look at my code?

```
<button onclick="myfunction()">Click Me</button>

<script>
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();


function myFunction(xml) {
    var a, b, c, d, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    a = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
    b = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author");
    c = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year");
    d = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
        txt += a[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ": " + b[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", " + c[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", " + d[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br><hr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

It looks like this when I load the html file, but I want to show the values after I click the button

[image]

Comment: it works fine if I am using `<p id="demo"></p>`.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? It's always easier when you are specific on what you are trying to do, what is happening, and what you were expecting. Is the function not being called? Did you spell it correctly?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I want to show the values below the button after I click the button

Comment: include the element with id:demo. Otherwise there is no place to print the text

Comment: Now it shows before I click the button, how can I make it show after I click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to replace `onclick="myfunction()"` to  `onclick="myFunction"` Note that the **F** is capital.

Second, you need to include the `<p>` tag on the page. This is where you are trying to display the content.

Here is your final html:

```
<button onclick="myfunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```